# Calling Visual Studio 2005 external tool without changing focus

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

While editing a file I want to use a hotkey to call an External Tool that I have setup to use the "Output" tab.  Currently when I use the hotkey the focus leaves the edit pane and goes to the "Output" window - I want the focus to not change from the edit pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Visual Studio macro (inspiration from Stephen Nutt) an acceptable (to me) workaround is:

```
Public Module RunTestExternalTool
    Sub RunExternalTool1andReturnFocusToEdit()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ExternalCommand1")
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.ViewCode")
    End Sub
End Module
```

This makes an assumption that the user wants to return focus the the ViewCode pane (no matter where they started).

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a macro to your hotkey and executing the external tool from the macro.  You can create a new macro using the Macro Editor by pressing Alt-F11.

Comment: Unfortunately using a macro to call the external tool still switches focus to the "Output" tab.  Thanks for making me aware of Visual Studio macros though.